# How do I export multiple separate objects in an obj file?

Tags: objects, export

I just made a simple test model in Blender but when I export it (as .obj) all the objects are bunched together. How do I make it so the shapes are separate manipulate-able pieces?

The model (it's just a test one)...

[image: Blender snap shot]

And if it helps here is the model in text format...

```
# Blender v2.77 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib obj_test.mtl
o Cube.001
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -3.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -3.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 3.000000 -0.999999
v -1.000001 3.000000 1.000001
v -3.000000 3.000000 1.000000
v -3.000000 3.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1//1 2//1 3//1 4//1
f 5//2 8//2 7//2 6//2
f 1//3 5//3 6//3 2//3
f 2//4 6//4 7//4 3//4
f 3//5 7//5 8//5 4//5
f 5//6 1//6 4//6 8//6
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 1.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 9//7 10//7 11//7 12//7
f 13//8 16//8 15//8 14//8
f 9//9 13//9 14//9 10//9
f 10//10 14//10 15//10 11//10
f 11//11 15//11 16//11 12//11
f 13//12 9//12 12//12 16//12
```

Also if it matters to anyone I'm using this model in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The lines that follow show that your two cubes are contained as two separate objects:

```
*snip*
o Cube.001
*snip*
o Cube
*snip*
```

If the point of failure is how they behave upon import into Unity, it may be better to phrase the question for that community.

Also, exports to FBX are supported in Blender: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html

In any case, there's no way to further separate the object coordinates in obj format than they are already, other than exporting each cube to it's own file.

Are you perhaps asking "How do I independently manipulate two objects from a single obj file in Unity?"?

Hope that helps.

Comment: "Are you perhaps asking "How do I independently manipulate two objects from a single obj file in Unity?"?" Pretty much yes. I will ask the Unity community in a bit. Thanks.